# Unable to use function with imported object

Tags: javascript

I'm rebuilding a website which contains basic introductions to characters in the fighting game *Tekken 7*. I've stored all the characters and their data as objects in one file.

```
/* CHARACTERS */
const characters = {
    // Akuma
    akuma: {
        // Profile
        name: "Akuma (Gouki)",
        nickname: "The Raging Demon",

        flag: "../img/flagicons/unknown.svg",
        image: "../img/characters/akuma.png",

        age: "Unknown",
        country: "Unknown",
        fightingStyle: "Ansatsuken, Satsui no Hadō",
        debut: "<em>Tekken 7</em>",

        // Scores
        offense: 10,
        defence: 10,
        range: 7,
        punishment: 7,

        gimmicks: 4,
        execution: 5,
        hurtbox: 3,

        // Playstyle
        playstyle: `Offensive, unorthodox, "MESSATSU!"`,
        introduction: "<p>Guest character from Capcom's <em>Street Fighter</em> series with great offensive tools and some of the highest damage output in the game thanks to his meter and special moves. However, a lot of his key moves come with some risk, generally being either unsafe on block or leaving him vulnerable in mid-air.</p>",
    },
    get gouki() {
        return this.akuma;
    },
    get gōki() {
        return this.akuma;
    },

    // Heihachi Mishima
    heihachi: {
        // Profile
        name: "Heihachi Mishima",
        nickname: "The King of Iron Fist",

        flag: "../img/flagicons/japan.svg",
        image: "../img/characters/heihachi-2.png",

        age: 75,
        country: "Japan (citizenship denied by government)",
        fightingStyle: "Mishima-ryū karate",
        debut: "<em>Tekken</em>",

        // Scores
        offense: 9,
        defence: 7,
        range: 8,
        punishment: 7,

        gimmicks: 3,
        execution: 4,
        hurtbox: 4,

        // Playstyle
        playstyle: "Offensive, Mishima",
        introduction: "<p>Offensive Mishima character with great poking, good counter hit tools, great damage output and good range. However, a lot of his best lows are launch punishable if not just unsafe on block, while his WS/FC punishment is mediocre.</p>",
    },

    // Kazumi Mishima
    kazumi: {
        // Profile
        name: "Kazumi Mishima",
        nickname: "The Assassin of Hachijō",

        flag: "../img/flagicons/japan.svg",
        image: "../img/characters/kazumi.png",

        age: "Unknown (deceased)",
        country: "Japan",
        fightingStyle: "Hachijō-ryū karate, Mishima-ryū karate",
        debut: "<em>Tekken 7</em>",

        // Scores
        offense: 9,
        defence: 7,
        range: 7,
        punishment: 7,

        gimmicks: 3,
        execution: 1,
        hurtbox: 2,

        // Playstyle
        playstyle: "Offensive, poking",
        introduction: "<p>Offensive character who, despite her name, lacks a big chunk of the Mishima-style toolset that her family members possess but more than makes up for it with great poking, great pressure tools, good counter hit tools and great range (partly thanks to her teleporting pet tiger). However, she lacks range on some key punishers, while most of her best lows are quite slow and unreliable for pressure.</p>",
    },
}

/* EXPORTING CHARACTERS */
export { characters };
```

I'm then attempting to export to another file that contains a function to display the given haracter's data on a web page, accepting that character's name as its sole argument. However, when I check the console on my browser, I get a SyntaxError that says "Cannot use import statement outside a module". What's the issue here?

```
/* IMPORTING CHARACTERS */
import { characters } from './character-list.js';


/* DECLARATIONS */
// Profile
let charName = document.getElementById("char-name");
let charNickname = document.getElementById("nickname");

let charFlag = document.getElementById("flag");
let charImg = document.getElementById("image");

let charAge = document.getElementById("age");
let charCountry = document.getElementById("country");
let charFightingStyle = document.getElementById("fighting-style");
let charDebut = document.getElementById("first-appearance");

// Scores
let charOffense = document.getElementById("offense");
let charDefence = document.getElementById("defence");
let charRange = document.getElementById("range");
let charPunishment = document.getElementById("punishment");

let charGimmicks = document.getElementById("gimmicks");
let charExecution = document.getElementById("execution");
let charHurtbox = document.getElementById("hurtbox");

// Playstyle and Intro
let charPlaystyle = document.getElementById("playstyle");
let charIntro = document.getElementById("introduction");


/* DISPLAY FUNCTION */
const display = character => {
    charName.innerHTML = characters[character].name;
    charNickname.innerHTML = characters[character].nickname;

    charFlag.src = characters[character].flag;
    charImg.src = characters[character].image;

    charAge.innerHTML = characters[character].age;
    charCountry.innerHTML = characters[character].country;
    charFightingStyle.innerHTML = characters[character].fightingStyle;
    charDebut.innerHTML = characters[character].debut;

    charOffense.innerHTML = characters[character].offense;
    charDefence.innerHTML = characters[character].defence;
    charRange.innerHTML = characters[character].range;
    charPunishment.innerHTML = characters[character].punishment;

    charGimmicks.innerHTML = characters[character].gimmicks;
    charExecution.innerHTML = characters[character].execution;
    charHurtbox.innerHTML = characters[character].hurtbox;

    charPlaystyle.innerHTML = characters[character].playstyle;
    charIntro.innerHTML = characters[character].introduction;
}


/* CALLING DISPLAY FUNCTION */
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let char = params.get("view");
display(char);
```

Comment: In your `<script` tag are you including `type='module'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) states:

> The static import statement is used to import read only live bindings
> which are exported by another module. **Imported modules are in strict
> mode whether you declare them as such or not. The import statement
> cannot be used in embedded scripts unless such script has a
> type="module".** Bindings imported are called live bindings because they
> are updated by the module that exported the binding.
>
> There is also a function-like dynamic import(), which does not require
> scripts of type="module".

**TL;DR** :
Add `type = "module"` when using the `<script>` tag when using `import`.

Comment: When I add type=module to the script in my code, I get the error "character.html:1 Access to script at '[file path here]' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https."

Comment: that's another issue. anyway, how are you serving the files? from disk directly? (`file:///`)..

Comment: Yeah directly from the disk. I'm trying to host the website locally first and make sure everything's okay before moving it to a web server.

Comment: just  use some local server like [`lite-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server), `nginx`, or any http server and should be okay